# Get values from URL as array. JInput

Tags: arrays, joomla, jinput

How can I get string values from URL and save them as array, right now URL looks like this `somename[]=xxxxxxxxx&somename[]=zzzzzzzzz&somename[]=zsdasd`

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$nameArray = $jinput->get('somename');
```

If I var_dump `$nameArray` I get this `Array` and I var_dump `$jinput` I get this:

```
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [somename] => Array
            (
            [0] => xxxxxxxxx
            [1] => zzzzzzzzz
            [2] => zsdasd
        )

    [option] => com_content
    [view] => featured
    [Itemid] => 101
)
```

I want to echo `$nameArray` like `$nameArray[0]` and get results `"xxxxxxxxxx"` but now i get `Array` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
$somename = JRequest::getVar('somename',array(),'', 'ARRAY');

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($somename);
```

Hope its helps..